# iText7 rectangle moves not the correct way

Tags: c#, canvas, itext, itext7

I have rotated paragraph.
That paragraph is in rectangle that appears in xy point, but it GROWING DOWN. 
[image: HERE] 

I want this rectangle to GROW UP like here 
[image: THIS]

Here is my code.

```
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, new Rectangle(
                 float.Parse(_xJobID, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * POINT, //dynamic x in mm
                 float.Parse(_yJobID, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * POINT, //dynamic y in mm
                8f,
                0));

        DeviceRgb rgb = new DeviceRgb(0, 0, 0); //black
        Color szin = Color.ConvertRgbToCmyk(rgb);
        DeviceRgb rgbGreen = new DeviceRgb(152, 251, 152); //green
        Color szinGreen = Color.ConvertRgbToCmyk(rgbGreen);

        canvas.Add(new Paragraph($"{_jobID}_{_client}") // dynamic text that goes down not up
            .SetRotationAngle(DegreeConvertation("90"))  //rotaded paragraph.
            .SetFont(ARIAL)
            .SetFontSize(5)
            .SetFontColor(szin).SetBackgroundColor(szinGreen).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT));
```

**What should I change to make the text rise up from the xy bottom left.**

Comment: To run your code one needs to know the definitions of `DegreeConvertation`, `ARIAL`, `_xJobID`, `_yJobID`, `POINT`. Please make the code easier to run for the SO users while still keeping it minimal - just remove the unnecessary stuff (`setFont` is probably unrelated to your problem) and simplify calls to undefined methods / variables by constants, e.g. you can easily substitute `float.Parse(_xJobID, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * POINT` with the real number you get from that call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of paragraph I used method *ShowTextAligned*.
 It shows perfect one line.

```
canvas.SetFont(ARIAL).SetFontSize(5.0F).SetFontColor(szin); // font
canvas.ShowTextAligned(
                       $"SomeText",
                       100,
                       100,
                       TextAlignment.LEFT,
                       VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM,
                       (float)Math.PI / 2
                      );
canvas.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by changing SetRotationAngle to 270 degrees.